# W3 Validation error, nested tags in an anchor tag

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I have the following html code in my page:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="best-price.php">
<div id="bestprice">
</div><!--visitorinfo-->
</a>
```

At the validator I have the following message:

```
<div id="bestprice">
```

> The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which
>   you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that
>   are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This
>   might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've
>   forgotten to close a previous element.
>
> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put
>   a block-level element (such as "`<p>`" or "`<table>`") inside an inline
>   element (such as "`<a>`", "`<span>`", or "`<font>`").

Any ideas?

Comment: `<div>` is "block" element and `<a>` is "inline" element.  You should not put a block element inside an inline element.  Use `<span>` instead of `div` or put the anchor inside of the `div`.

Comment: Your `div` is empty. There is nowhere to click, perhaps

Comment: `<div>` is not allowed inside `<a>`. That's pretty much what the error says.

Comment: @Sparky This is no longer true with HTML5 and you can put block elements inside anchors.

Comment: @Rob, yes, but apparently the OP is not using HTML5 or he would not have recieved this particular error message.

Comment: You should be far more worried about a link containing only whitespace characters than about validation (which depends on HTML version and isn’t particularly interesting here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put a `<div>` tag inside of an `<a>` tag for doctypes prior to HTML5. But you could do something like this.

```
<a class="fancybox" href="best-price.php">
   <span id="bestprice">
   </span>
</a>
```

**4.01 transitional:** http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> -->
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="fancybox" href="best-price.php">
   <span id="bestprice">
   </span>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML5:** http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="fancybox" href="best-price.php">
    <span id="bestprice">
    </span>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

*Note: As Rob mentioned in the comments. This,*

```
<a class="fancybox" href="best-price.php">
    <div id="bestprice">
    </div>
</a>
```

*Will validate in HTML5, but not in the older doctypes.*

Comment: This is no longer true and anchors can now contain div elements.

Comment: @sdcr That's a problem with the browser and not validation.

Comment: @Rob, yes that is correct for HTML5, I added that to the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<span>` to replace `<div>`

```
<a class="fancybox" href="best-price.php">
    <span id="bestprice">
        blabla
    </span><!--visitorinfo-->
</a>
```

And add CSS, to make it acts like a block element:

```
#bestprice {
    display: block;
}
```